# Migrating from apache zookeeper (incubator chart) to bitnami/zookeeper chart

Tags: kubernetes-helm, apache-zookeeper, bitnami

I have an old zookeeper (i.e. https://charts.helm.sh/incubator) with 3 replicas of statefulsets running. Now, I wanted to move to bitnami/zookeeper with similar 3 replica.

Now, I have both old and new zookeeper running,  the problem is data sync is not happening between the old and new zookeepers. Because bitnami zookeeper uses a different file structure and location with is not the same as the old one. I believe the PVC is still there, but how to re-use those data in the new cluster?

The screenshot shows how the data looks like in zookeeper cli, I want to use or process those data with new cluster.

[image]

Any suggestion, on how to make the data sync or copy the data from the PVC and accessible from new bitnami zookeeper?

Any help would be appreciated.